# Can a matrix whose entries are real, and has positive eingenvalues, have a negative entry?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a matrix whose entries are real, and has positive eingenvalues, have a negative entry?

We assume also that its characteristic polynomial is "fully" factorizable into first-degree (real) polynomial factors.

Comment: Please make the body of your Question as self-contained as possible, and avoid relying entirely on the title to pose the problem you would like to ask about.  Presumably your "fully" factorizable polynomial may be said to "split" into linear (first-degree) factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

$$\left [\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1\\0 & 2\end{array}\right]$$

Characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda -1)(\lambda -2)$.